# Вывод даты слева от заголовка

Tags: html, css

Есть список новостей, хочу вывести дату слева от заголовка новости, но не знаю как.

Вот пример:
[image: Картинка, как пример]

Код

```
        <div class="next-news">
            <a class="news-title" href="news?id=11">SOME NEWS FROM 09.06.2019</a><br>
            <span class="news-date">09.06.2019</span>
        </div>
        <div class="next-news">
            <a class="news-title" href="news?id=10">SMALL NEWS FROM 31.05.2019</a><br>
            <span class="news-date">31.05.2019</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a class="news-title" href="news?id=9">SHOP UPDATE</a><br>
            <span class="news-date">10.05.2019</span>
        </div>
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 5):

Например использовать `flex` с `row-reverse`:

```css
.next-news {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.news-date {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="next-news">
  <a class="news-title" href="news?id=11">SOME NEWS FROM 09.06.2019</a><br>
  <span class="news-date">09.06.2019</span>
</div>
<div class="next-news">
  <a class="news-title" href="news?id=10">SMALL NEWS FROM 31.05.2019</a><br>
  <span class="news-date">31.05.2019</span>
</div>
<div class="next-news">
  <a class="news-title" href="news?id=9">SHOP UPDATE</a><br>
  <span class="news-date">10.05.2019</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

a[href^='news'] {
  line-height: 70px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a[href^='news']::before {
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

a[href='news?id=11']::before {
  content: '09.06.2019';
}

a[href='news?id=10']::before {
  content: '31.05.2019';
}

a[href='news?id=9']::before {
  content: '10.05.2019';
}
```

```html
<div class="next-news">
  <a class="news-title" href="news?id=11">SOME NEWS FROM 09.06.2019</a><br>
  <span class="news-date">09.06.2019</span>
</div>
<div class="next-news">
  <a class="news-title" href="news?id=10">SMALL NEWS FROM 31.05.2019</a><br>
  <span class="news-date">31.05.2019</span>
</div>
<div>
  <a class="news-title" href="news?id=9">SHOP UPDATE</a><br>
  <span class="news-date">10.05.2019</span>
</div>
```

Но с помощью флексов будет лучше

Answer (score 0):

```css
.next-news {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.next-news::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.next-news br {
  display: none;
}

.next-news .news-title,
.next-news .news-date {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  min-height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.next-news .news-title {
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  font-size: 20px;
}

.next-news .news-date {
  width: 80px;
  font-size: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="next-news">
  <a class="news-title" href="news?id=11">SOME NEWS FROM 09.06.2019</a>
  <br>
  <span class="news-date">09.06.2019</span>
</div>
<div class="next-news">
  <a class="news-title" href="news?id=10">SMALL NEWS FROM 31.05.2019</a>
  <br>
  <span class="news-date">31.05.2019</span>
</div>
<div class="next-news">
  <a class="news-title" href="news?id=9">SHOP UPDATE</a>
  <br>
  <span class="news-date">10.05.2019</span>
</div>
```